# How to get ResultSet string array?

Tags: java, kotlin, crate

I have a query that is hitting a table that has an array column.  When I am processing my records I would like to take the array column's data and treat it like a string array and grab the first value.  I had assumed I could do the following:

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
    val clients = resultSet.getArray("clients")
    println(clients[0])
}
```

But when I do this I get the error:

> Error:(34, 3) Kotlin: Unresolved reference. None of the following
>   candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
>   @InlineOnly public operator inline fun <@OnlyInputTypes K, V> Map.get(key: Int): ??? defined in kotlin.collections
>   @SinceKotlin public operator fun MatchGroupCollection.get(name:
>   String): MatchGroup? defined in kotlin.text

`getArray` returns type `Array!` so I had assumed I could access values by index.  What do I have to do to access this array of values?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, [`getArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) returns a [`java.sql.Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html).

This is not the same as the [`kotlin.Array`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/) type.

You can use [`getArray` on the `java.sql.Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html#getArray()), which would simply be translated to `array` in Kotlin:

```
resultSet.getArray("clients").array
```

to get the actual array as an `Object`/`Any`.

You can cast it to an `Array<out Any?>`:

```
val arr = resultSet.getArray("clients").array as Array<out Any?>
```

or to the desired type directly, though you may get some `ClassCastException`s as a result.

To stay type-safe, you may want something like

```
val firstClient = (resultSet.getArray("clients").array as? Array<out Any?>)
        ?.filterIsInstance<String>()
        ?.firstOrNull()
```

This will:

- result in `null` if the array does not contain `String`s
- result in `null` if the array is empty
- result in the first `String` if the array contains a `String`